# How to get top level parent of div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to know how to get the top level parent of a div. I know you can use `parent()`, but I have a click function on multiple divs

```
<div class="parent" data-row="1">
  <div class="cat div1">
    <div class="sub-cat div1_1">content</div>
    <div class="sub-cat div1_2">content</div>
    <div class="sub-cat div1_3">
      <div class="inner-cat 1_3_3">innercontent</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cat div2">
    <div class="sub-cat div2_1">content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Let's say I have a parent div, with a parent class name, which also includes an index number in `data-row`.

I have click functions on the `.sub-cat`, `.inner-cat` and `.cat`, however, I want to get the `data-row` function with every click.

I've tried retrieving the data-row by using `$(this).closest('.parent')` to get to the parent div, but that doesn't work as in it returns length `0`.

Comment: can you share your jquery code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To achieve this you can use `closest()`. `parents()` is an alternative, but `closest()` performs better as it stops at the first match.

```js
$('.cat, .innercat, .sub-cat').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  var row = $(this).closest('.parent').data('row');
  console.log(row);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent" data-row="1">
  <div class="cat div1">
    <div class="sub-cat div1_1">content</div>
    <div class="sub-cat div1_2">content</div>
    <div class="sub-cat div1_3">
      <div class="inner-cat 1_3_3">innercontent</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cat div2">
    <div class="sub-cat div2_1">content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also note the use of `stopPropagation()` in the event handler to stop the event bubbling up and being caught by nested elements.

Comment: plus 1 from me because yes, you're right `closest` is the better solution.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan Does the stopPropagation, also prevents other functions from executing?

Comment: @Elvira if they are attached to events on parents of the element that raised the original event, then yes it will.

Answer (score 2):

You want `parents(".parent")` which will walk all the way up the parent tree

```js
$('.cat, .sub-cat, .inner-cat').on("click", function(){
    var $parent = $(this).parents(".parent");
    console.log($parent.data("row"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent" data-row="1">
  <div class="cat div1">
      <div class="sub-cat div1_1">content</div>
      <div class="sub-cat div1_2">content</div>
      <div class="sub-cat div1_3">
          <div class="inner-cat 1_3_3">innercontent</div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cat div2">
     <div class="sub-cat div2_1">content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```